# RewriteRule for renaming a URL

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

My Current rewrite rule is

```
RewriteRule ^tpjobs/(.+)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With Joomla Core SEF plugin

And My URL is coming like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/tpjobs/findresume.html
```

Please suggest me how to take off **tpjobs** or renaming to **tpjobs** to **jobs**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tpjobs/(.*)$ /jobs/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will redirect all `http://www.mydomain.com/tpjobs/foo` to `http://www.mydomain.com/jobs/foo`

Comment: I AM USING BELOW .htaccess

    ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
    RewriteRule ^tpjobs/(.*)$ /jobs/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
    #
    ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

Comment: Would it be possible to append your .htaccess code in your question so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Understand that .htaccess will redirect inbound traffic from one address to another - but the original link (in the page) will still contain the full (unwanted) portions of the url.

If you want to change the 'actual' link - ie the html that is present in the page - you will need to build your own router.php file for the component in question - OR - you will need to write a content plugin to rewrite your content using a regular expression.